# Illegal Instruction for NordVPN

Tags: pi-zero-w

I'm fairly new into all of this and normally just try to follow guides on how to install things,
I followed the NordVPN installation for Raspberry Pi, but after trying to do the "nordvpn login" command, I received a "illegal instruction". I am unsure how to fix it and would appreciate any help. I have tried doing 'sudo apt-get-update' and this is what it returned:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
Hit:3 https://repo.nordvpn.com//deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

other than that, I still get 'illegal instruction'

If there is any more info needed, I am willing to provide it. Thanks!

I am using a Raspberry Pi Zero W Rev 1.1 (not sure if this helps)

Comment: Welcome. "Illegal instruction" indicates the binary you are trying to execute is incompatible with the hardware.  You likely have installed software targeting armv7 (Pi 2+) or armv8 (Pi 3+), the Zero W is armv6.  Running `file $(which nordvpn)` (presuming "nordvpn" is the command and it is a binary and not a symlink or script) should confirm that; edit the output into the question or leave it in a comment here.

Comment: Hello @goldilocks, I hope you do not mind the tag. I've done "file $nordvpn" and this is what it showed me:

```Usage: file [-bcCdEhikLlNnprsvzZ0] [--apple] [--extension] [--mime-encoding]
            [--mime-type] [-e <testname>] [-F <separator>]  [-f <namefile>]
            [-m <magicfiles>] [-P <parameter=value>] <file> ...
       file -C [-m <magicfiles>]
       file [--help]```

Comment: *"I've done `file $nordvpn` and..."* -> I don't understand why you would do that and the result does not surprise me, unless you mean you actually did `file $(which nordvpn)`, which is not at all the same thing.  If it happened that way, you'll need to show the output from just plain `which nordvpn`.